# Crash when trying to run a new thread to add Google Maps markers

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to start a new Thread to add markers on the map after parsing a JSON response and storing it in a hashmap. After this async task is finished, I want to add new markers on the map by iterating through the hashmap values and using `addMarkers()`. When I run my app it crashes and I get this error.

Logcat error:

```
at com.google.k.a.cj.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ca.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addMarker(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
at com.example.test.testapp.MapsActivity$ParseJSON$1.run(MapsActivity.java:169)
```

MapsActivity

```
public class ParseJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(status == 200)
            {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                String noHTML = stripHtml(data);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(noHTML);

                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    NearbyStops stops = new NearbyStops();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("ID");
                    stops.name = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                    stops.lat = jsonObject.getDouble("Lat");
                    stops.lng = jsonObject.getDouble("Long");

                    stopHash.put(id, stops);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        Thread addMarkers = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for(NearbyStops value : stopHash.values())
                {
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                    String name = value.name;
                    double lat = value.lat;
                    double lng = value.lng;

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title(name);
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }
            }
        });
        addMarkers.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't update UI from any other threab beside UI (main) thread. Use View.post or runOnUiThread if you have to, but foreach in onPostExecute should suffice

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, im new to android programming. it i thought that you needed to update all UI components on a new thread

Comment: Not new thread, it must be on main thread, ic case of AsyncTask: doInBackground is separate worker thread, and onPreExecute, onPostExecute, onProgressUpdate are on UI(main) thread, so from there you can update UI components. Btw good luck with learning android :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have doubt, as you are accessing `mMap` Google Map object on Worker Thread. So Just remove `addMarkers Thread` in `onPostExecute()` and directly put for loop for adding markers in `onPostExceute()` And you are referring some Objects like, `stopHash` in `addMarker` Thread which is not accessible (means you are referring `stopHash` with no values in it or may be `null`).

Comment: thank you. this fixed it i thought that you needed to updateUI on a new thread or asynctask.

Comment: @user1281921 - Android UI only accessible from Main Application UI thread. So whenever you have to write any long operation put it in worker thread and after just access its results in Application's main UI Thread.

Comment: @user1281921 - So in your above code, `doInBackground()` runs in Worker Thread and `onPostExecute()` will run on Application's main UI Thread.